# HyperPay Integration With Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Dears, Any body has an experience with HypePay Payment Method?

I need to integrate HyperPay with Magento 2. Is there is any extension or Custom Code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is paid extension for HyperPay. 
[HyperPay Extension : http://eextensions.co/hyperpay-payment-gateway-in-popup-magento-2.html](http://eextensions.co/hyperpay-payment-gateway-in-popup-magento-2.html)

Note : I have not used this extension. So before purchase, ask queries on this extension support.

Answer (score -1):

HyperPay provides a payment extension that supports Magento2 please contact HyperPay technical team on technical@hyperpay.com and they shall provide you with the latest extension.

Comment: No need to down vote this answer as it leads to appropriate solution 
and they have this opensource extension in  https://github.com/HyperpayOpenSource/Magento-2-Plugin