# Magento 2 upload image from customer registration page

Tags: magento-2.1, image-upload

I have a requirement in Magento 2 where i need to upload an image from customer registration page and from admin panel. I have created a file type attribute using below code, attribute is created successfully and upload button is coming but i am not getting data saved.

```
   <?php
namespace W3solver\Callforprice\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

    protected $customerSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0) {

            $setup->startSetup();
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'twilio_image', [
                'type' => 'string',
                'label' => 'Twilio Image',
                'input' => 'file',
                "source" => '',
                'required' => false,
                'default' => '0',
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 210,
                'position' => 210,
                'system' => false,
            ]);

            $image = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'twilio_image')
                    ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ]);

            $image->save();
            $setup->endSetup();
        }  
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me the way to do this??

Comment: Review my question, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2/186384#186384

Comment: @Jsparo30 that helped, i was setting wrong input, you saved my time. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, Can you save my time also :) and answer the question?  also you can check this question (the same)  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187299/sign-up-with-customer-image-attribute-rest-api-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment259237_187299

Comment: sure, glad to help, check i updated the answer in the post.

Comment: Thank you, Kindly can you help me to build an extension related to this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187113/hyperpay-integration-with-magetno-2